# Angular 2 - when *ngFor completes call function on parent component

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am trying to create a carousel component for my Angular 2 application.

I want the carousel to be generic, so that it will support both these cases:

```html
<myCarousel>
  <div>first card</div>
  <div>second card</div>
  ....
</myCarousel>
```

and the more generic

```html
<myCarousel>
  <myCard *ngFor="let card of cards" [card]="card"></myCard>
</myCarousel>
```

The problem is that the carousel component requires an initialisation to run *after* the *ngFor has completed, otherwise it won't be displayed correctly.

Since the data is coming from a web service call, I can't guess the exact timing, but I need the carousel component to observe, implicitly or explicitly, when *ngFor has completed. Can anybody help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another Stackoverflow answer that already solves the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36750875/463893

My solution is very similar: a directive (called CarouselItem) applied to the carousel elements inside the *ngFor, defining a boolean input that tells whether the element is the last, and a property (or eventemitter) that can be set to a function to call when the last element has been reached.

So the template becomes:

```html
<myCarousel #carousel>
  <myCard *ngFor="let card of cards; let l = last"
           [card]="card"
           CarouselItem
           [ready]="l ? true : false"
           [init]="carousel.initialize">
  </myCard>
</myCarousel>
```

the variable #carousel is needed to be able to reference the carousel component from the myCard directive ( [init]="carousel.initialize"  ).

The following is the code of the directive:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: `[CarouselItem]`
})
export class CarouselItem {

  @Input('init') onInit: Function = () => {};

  @Input() set ready(isReady: boolean) {
      if (isReady)
        setTimeout(()=>this.onInit(), 200);
  };
}
```

And finally the carousel component contains a public initialization method.

```js
public initialize= ()=> {
    // perform initialisation
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Fire event on last attempt of `ngFor` as below

```
<myCard *ngFor="#card in cards;  #last=last" [card]="card" [attr.ready]="last ? false : true"></myCard>
```

and in code do this

```
@Input()
set ready(isReady: boolean) {
    if (isReady) someCallbackMethod();
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, but could you be a bit more clear?
In which component is the ready attribute defined? I've tried to define it on the carousel component but I don't seem to be able to reference it.

This is what I tried, upsetting the template compiler :)

<myCarousel #theCarousel>
   <myCard *ngFor="#card in cards;  #last=last" [card]="card" [theCarousel.ready]="last ? false : true"></myCard>
</myCarousel>

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ContentChildren`.

```js
@ContentChildren(MyCardComponent) cards: QueryList<MyCardComponent>;

ngOnAfterContentInit() {
   this.cards
      .changes
      //.debounce(100) /* maybe add an additional debounce time.. */
      .subscribe(cards => {
         // received new cards..
   });
}
```

Comment: No, I don't think this would work, as I want the cards to be completely generic- it could be MyCard or MyPicture or anything else. Otherwise I end up having a carousel component that is tightly bound to one specific type of content.