# In the HTML view/template of an Angular app how to wait for rendering of ngFor section?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-material2

Assume this scenario:

You have just received matrix/table style data from a database source - in variable:
*dataSource*

Now, you want to present the data in a table - e.g mat-table.
The catch is your data fields needs some manipulation while being rendered using the classic Anular: *ngFor and it takes some time to render the table.

What would be a good approach to designing the HTML template/view so it displays text:

***Building report ...***

while *ngFor is rendering.

When the table is ready (*ngFor has rendered the last row) we hide the ***Building report ...*** text and display the rendered table instead.

This template code simply shows a blank page while the page is being rendered. I would like the user to see the text of  ***Building report ...*** instead.

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="dataSource">

    <div class= "table-container mat-elevation-z8">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" 
      *ngFor="let column of colPropNames">

      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>

    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayCols; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayCols;"></tr>

      </table>

      <div class="box-paginator">
    <mat-paginator class="paginator"
        color="primary"
        [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" 
        showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator>
      </div>
    </div>

  </ng-container>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has an `if else` [feature](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf):

```
<div *ngIf="show; else elseBlock">Text to show</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Alternate text while primary text is hidden</ng-template>
```

so you can edit you code to display your required text in the `else block`:

first add this to your `*ngIf`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dataSource; else elseBlock">
```

and display your text like so:

```
 <ng-template #elseBlock>Building report ...</ng-template>
```

Comment: I understand this part well. The dataSource is not the delay. The data has already arrived. We have it. Now we are rendering it using ngFor. The rendering of the data inside the ngFor takes time. We are waiting for that part to complete and for that section, we need to display the waiting message ...

Comment: Oh i misunderstood you, check this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930435/angular-2-when-ngfor-completes-call-function-on-parent-component

Comment: and this one, you should be able to solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750678/calling-a-directive-after-the-load-of-last-item-in-ngfor/36750875#36750875